# interpolating HTML attributes in ERB for rails broken?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, erb

I want to interpolate an attribute **and** its value in an html tag.
If I only interpolate the value like this:

```
<span b="<%= "1 2 3"%>">
```

It works, resulting in:

```html
<span b="1 2 3">
```

If I try to interpolate the attribute as well like this:

```
<span <%= "b='1 2 3'" %> >
```

Instead of the same result as before I get:

```html
<span b="'1" 2="" 3&#39;="">
```

what's going on? Where's the documentation describing this behavior?

**UPDATE**:
The extra quotes in the las example where added apparently by the browser, not ERB, that got me confused. ERB render the string as `<span b=&quot;1 2 3&quot;>` so the browser assumes this is meant `<span b="&quot;1" 2="" 3&quot;="">` and then resolve the entities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What going on here is [HTML escaping](https://makandracards.com/makandra/2579-everything-you-know-about-html_safe-is-wrong). In Rails unless you use  [`raw`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/OutputSafetyHelper.html#method-i-raw) or [`String#html_safe`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/String.html#method-i-html_safe) the entities in the string will be escaped which helps prevent cross site scripting attacks.

So if you do:

```
<span <%= raw "b='1 2 3'" %> >
```

This will produce the intended output. But a better way altogether is to use the `tag` helpers instead if the HTML you are creating is highly dynamic. String interpolation tends to get really lengthy and is hard to read.

```
<%= tag.span(b: "1 2 3") %>

<% end %>
```

Whatever hash arguments you pass are added as attributes to the tag.

Comment: I meant the ERB interpolation (injected via `<%= %>`) The string interpolation is also intended but not shown in my example (would be `"b='#{something}'"`). This only happens on html attributes, so ERB knows it is not just inserting the resulting string into some html, but within the a html tag?

Comment: @estani No thats completely wrong, Rails escapes html entities in strings period. ERB/Rails knows nothing about the html you are constructing. A template is just a string buffer. The only difference between your two examples is that `"1 2 3"` does not contain any entities that are escaped while `"b='1 2 3'"` does.

Comment: But there are quotes being added... hmm... those were added by the browser! that makes much more sense now.

Comment: Use view source to see the raw html rendered. What you are seeing is most likely when the browser goes into slop mode and tries to deal with broken html.

Comment: indeed. I've updating the question, because that was exactly what got me confused.

Answer (score -1):

you need to deeply understand the difference between using ' and "

' single quote -  will out without any interpretation

"" double quotes - will output only after interpretation

in order to get the output you need, you can code like

```
<span <%= 'b="1 2 3"' %> >
```

Comment: Thanks, yes that is clear to me. You're solution causes the same error I mentioned before, as this has nothing to do with string interpolation.